# symfony swift mailer host name

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

This my `parameter.yml`

```
parameters:
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: mongodb
database_user: mongodb
database_password: *******
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: //which host?
mailer_user: support@domain.com
mailer_password: *****
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

And this is my `config.yml`

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
encryption: ssl
auth_mode: login
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

I tried different hosts like `~`,`127.0.0.1`,`localhost`,etc in the `mailer_host:` parameter.
But mail is not sending.

If I use Gmail account with,

```
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
```

the mail is sending properly.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have a SMTP daemon running on your machine. The daemon should then listen on an IP address or a machine hostname which you then put in the configuration.

Other thing you can do is to change the `mail_transport` parameter to `mail` or `sendmail` – those do not require SMTP daemon.

See [How to Send an Email](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) symfony documentation page.

Comment: How can I make SMTP daemon run in my machine?

Comment: Install and configure one. Choice will be dependent on your OS. Other thing you can do is to change the mail_transport parameter to `mail` or `sendmail` – those do not require smtp. See updated answer.